# Train model to detect good/bad picture quality

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, resnet

I am trying to train model to  detect good/bad picture quality. My approach is to "feed" model with two folders of picture. First one is with good picture, second one - same pictures, but corrupted.

I am wondering whether I am doing properly, as I am new in Tensorflow.

What I have done:

1) Cloned repo https://github.com/tensorflow/models

2) cd official/resnet

3)  python imagenet_main.py --data_dir=[PATH TO DATA] --model_dir=./my_model

I assume, that after "feeding" I will get model, which should detect if picture has good quality or not.

It does not matter right now if model will detect it properly, what is real important to me - Am I training in right way my model? Am I right to use imagenet_main.py with arguments dir to pictures (TFRecords) and dir, where my future model should be?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: a side comment: when you will finally train this model, at best it can detect only the corruptions you made on the "bad" set, but in pictures there can be a very huge number of characteristic which can make them bad. Just consider this when you will test the model on "real world" pictures

Comment: @Vincenzo Lavorini, thank you for your answer, I understand, that I have not correct approach to solution how to detect quality of picture, but right now, for first step it's okey for me. However, I would be thankful if you'll give me some recomentation about how to train model, which will detect properly if picture is corrupted or not.

Also, main question is - Am I training model right? I mean, will that model work at all or I am just wasting my time and will get "broken" model?